# Define validation properties outside Panel in Wicket

Tags: validation, properties, localization, wicket, panel

I need to define Wicket validation messages in **.properties** file of a page for a reusable panel. I will give an example (code snippets below):

**MyPage** class contains **MyPanel** with a fragment **MyFragment** in which there is a component called **MyComponent** (TextField of a type BigDecimal).

I need to define 3 instances of reusable MyPanel on the MyPage and I need to **define a validation key for the MyComponent in MyPage** (because they are used in a different context).

```
class MyPage extends WebPage { 

   public void onInitialize() { 
       super.onInitialize();
       add(new MyPanel("fuelConsumption"); 
       add(new MyPanel("populationGrowth"); 
       add(new MyPanel("averageGrade"); 
   }

}

class MyPanel extends Panel { 

   public void onInitialize() { 
       super.onInitialize();
       Fragment fragment = new MyFragment("fragment");         
       add(fragment); 
   }

   class MyFragment extends Fragment { 

      public void onInitialize() { 
          super.onInitialize();
          add(new MyComponent("component"); 
      }

   }

   class MyComponent extends TextField<BigDecimal> {
   }

}
```

So, I need to add a validation messages for all 3 usages of the MyComponent field of type BigDecimal into the MyPage.properties, something like:

```
fuelConsumption.fragment.component.IConverter.BigDecimal=Fuel consumption must be a decimal
populationGrowth.fragment.component.IConverter.BigDecimal=Please check the population growth format
averageGrade.fragment.component.IConverter.BigDecimal=This is not an average grade!
```

I deliberately use different kinds of validation messages, I don't want to use a single one with configurable parameter

When I add **MyPanel.properties** and put a line like this:

```
component.IConverter.BigDecimal=Component is not a valid BigDecimal.
```

it works fine, but I really want to specify it outside the reusable panel (so that the panel may be used in other ways and meanings).

How would I do that?

When I try to add the lines above, it does not work, nor in any way I tried, like omitting the "fragment" or "component" from the properties string. Nothing helps.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks good to me.

Enable debug logging for org.apache.wicket.resource.loader.ComponentStringResourceLoader to see which keys are searched.

Comment: Alright, thanks, it looks I have finally found where the problem is (though I have no idea why). I had the MyPanel implementations added into a Form in MyPage class. So adding "form" in front of the keys works - `form.fuelConsumption.fragment.component.IConverter.BigDecimal=Fuel consumption must be a decimal`, although when I use other similar components (non-panels, just simple textareas etc.) inside the very same form, it works fine wihtout the form key - e.g. `myTextarea.Required=Something`.

Comment: One more question - is there any way how to simplify the property notation? I mean re-routing the `componentName.fragment.component.IConverter.BigDecimal` to a shorter form of `componentName.IConverter.BigDecimal` ? I am not sure if I can do any such thing with a panel. Is there a way? Thanks.